# Android multiple file upload to server

Tags: java, android, file, upload, image-uploading

I have a problem in uploading images to server to better explain to you my problem I have prepared a pair of PHP script that would simulate what i want to happen.

```
PHP upload file ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action=destination.php method=post>
<input  type=file name=file1 />
<input  type=file name=file2 />
<input  type=submit name=submit />
</form>


    PHP destination file ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<?php

$files = array('file1', 'file2', 'file3');
$path = 'elp/pendingimages/';

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] > 0) {
        echo 'Error: '. $_FILES[$file]['error'] .'<br />';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Upload: '. $_FILES[$file]['name'] .'<br />';
        echo 'Type: '. $_FILES[$file]['type'] .'<br />';
        echo 'Size: '. ($_FILES[$file]['size'] / 1024) .' Kb<br />';
        echo 'Stored in: '. $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'] .'<br />';
    }
}

?>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

lets leave the destination file as is cause i wont be having control with the server I want to have the same function as the upload file in my JAVA code. I already have this but my prob is that only an row is inserted in the server

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setRequestProperty("image[]", fileName);
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[]\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + ";user_id=\"157\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
```

Comment: and what the problem is?

Comment: um only one parameter in read by the sever, I need to have multiple images uploaded at a time

Comment: Try adding Content-Length parameter when sending the images.

Answer (score 0):

I've write [tutorial about it](http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2012/06/18/membuat-file-upload-di-android-dan-php/) on my blog. It's in Bahasa Indonesia, though. In your problem, it is because you only upload one file. You will need to repeat the add upload field process.